# How to set the default author name in MS SQL 2005 stored procedure template in management studio?

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

In MS SQL Server Management Studio Express, is there a way to set the default author name to my name when I create a stored procedure by right clicking on the "Stored Procedures" folder under "Programmability" folder?  It would save me a lot of time if I don't have to keeping updating it whenever I create a new stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can completely edit what appears in the templates in Management Studio by going to View->Template Explorer-> Expand Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!
Is there a way to stamp create date with the current machine date automatically?

Comment: Hmm. that's a good question. I don't think so, as the token replacement functionality just expects "<name, type, value>", which corresponds to the columns in the Shift+Ctrl+M menu (specify values for tokens). Can't call getdate() or whatever. As far as i know anyway...